# error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'android'

Tags: android, android-emulator

I don't use this attribute in any xml file, even if when I set "2.3.3" android version to my project properties, I get this error. 
(If I set 4.1 clean works. But I want to find out why the app crash on real phone, so I tried to set to 2.3.3. The app doesn't crash on Android 2.2 Emulator)
And this one:

> Bad XML block: header size 63322 or total size 142711912 is larger than data size 0

Suggestions?

Comment: I can't even understand what you're trying to say. If your problem is crash on a real phone, what version is on the phone and how it relates to the rest of your question?

Comment: I coded an app which works on Android emulator, using Android 4.1 (set it in project properties). If I run it on the real phone, it crash and I don't understand why. 
So, I changed project properties fixing it to android 2.3.3, but launching a clean, I got the error I reported above.

Answer (score 3):

This is typical of declaring a target version lower than 11 (Honeycomb).   Some features are only available from 11 onward (same as Theme.Holo).

Change that in PROJECT > PROPERTIES > ANDROID (dont worry, it can hang for up to 10 minutes, check your sysMonitor, as long as eclipse is eating up CPU time, you are fine).

You may also have to change your version in your AndroidManifest.xml file

Answer (score 1):

Solved. 
I found out the problem by myself. 
I checked the xml file and deleted the reported attribute.